# Filter ObservableCollection by ICollectionView and use it

Tags: c#, generic-collections

I want to be able to filter my `ObservableCollection` based on user `filtering criteria`. At the moment i have `datagridview` which used this collection in `virtual mode`:

```
private ObservableCollection<WarehouseReadModel> _warehouse = new ObservableCollection<WarehouseReadModel>();
```

Is there any way to use instead ICollectionView? For instance when program starts it shows all data from `_warehouse` but when any filtering from `GUI` is done to assign it somehow to `ICollectionView` or even from begining to assign instead to ICollectionView without any filters and then apply filters when users wants it? If possible please of working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have two ObservableCollection properties (or fields) :

```
public ObservableCollection<WarehouseReadModel> AllWareHouses { get; set}
public ObservableCollection<WarehouseReadModel> DisplayWareHouses {get; set}
```

In the beginning, you will load all data in the first property "AllWareHouses".
When the user selects any filters, you will filter "AllWareHouses" with a LINQ query for instance.

The result of the query will be assigned to "DisplayWareHouses". you will use this property to bind to your DataGrid.

```
DisplayWareHouses = AllWareHourse.Where(...)
```

Comment: i was also thinking about that. And if user remove filters take data from AllWarehouses right? I am just thinking about other approach as if user removes filters instead taking data from ALlWarehouses - to also load data to AllWarehouse from db again as you can imagine if i would not to this then user could work with old data someone else already (other user) modifed. Or even keep one list - use linq if filters are needed, but if filters are removed take data from database again to that one list thats it. What you think?

Comment: yes if you want to make sure that data are up to date, you can reload from database.

Comment: so keep only one list at the end

Comment: I'll keep two lists, one for loading data (AllWarehouses) and one for filtering data (DisplayWareHouses), that will save you from round trip to the database when user changes filter (no need to load new data).  But if you want to load new data you can update AllWarehouses.

Comment: I prefer one list because using two list  - the one with original initial data will be too old in time when other users change some data,m i think its really better to take new fresh copy from database when removinf filters. But thats just my view on it. thanks